# Java How to determine the "lost" hour when changing to summertime?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone-offset

I would like to know if the DateTime `"2020-03-29 02:15"` exists due to the time change.
I found the `ZoneOffsetTransition` class, which has a `isGap()` method, but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: What exact information do you want? Just **if** that time exists or do you need more details about the gap if it exists? You can just get a `ZonedDateTime` from the date/time and zone you have and then check if toLocalTime() returns the same value as you passed in. If it doesn't, then the time fell into a gap.

Comment: I just want to know if there a gap or not. I will try your solution, thanks.

Comment: a poor mans solution, parse the full string and if check toString changes after instantiation:
final String stringFormat = "2020-03-29T02:15+01:00[Europe/Paris]";
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(stringFormat).toString().equals(stringFormat));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply convert to `ZonedDateTime` and back. `ZonedDateTime` insists on selecting an existing time, so if we get the same time back, it’s for real.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();

    String dateTimeString = "2020-03-29 02:15";

    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    LocalDateTime check = dateTime.atZone(zone).toLocalDateTime();
    if (check.equals(dateTime)) {
        System.out.println("This time exists");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This time does not exist; it is in the spring gap.");
        System.out.println("We got " + check);
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> This time does not exist; it is in the spring gap.
> We got 2020-03-29T03:15
> ```

From the documentation of `LocalDateTime.atZone()`:

> In the case of a gap, where clocks jump forward, there is no valid
>   offset. Instead, the local date-time is adjusted to be later by the
>   length of the gap. For a typical one hour daylight savings change, the
>   local date-time will be moved one hour later into the offset typically
>   corresponding to "summer".

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId))